# How to integrate heaviside(y-f) in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration

I am not able to integrate heaviside(y-f) for x= 0 to pi/2 and y = 0 to pi/2 (only syms integration "int"). After running the code, output is shown in below and I am not able to get the numerical answer. Can you give some ideas on how to proceed?

code:

```
syms x y
f = sin(x);
integ = int( int(heaviside(y-f), x, 0, pi/2),y, 0, pi/2)
```

Result:

```
integ =
 
int(int(heaviside(y - sin(x)), x, 0, pi/2), y, 0, pi/2)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Avoid symbolic calculation whenever possible.**

Notice the heaviside function can be defined as:

```
hvsd = @(x) (x > 0) + 0.5*(x == 0); % another name to do not overshadow heaviside
```

You can use either [integral2](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral2.html) or [trapz](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/trapz.html) to evaluate the numerical integral.

```
heaviside = @(x) (x > 0) + 0.5*(x == 0);
fun = @(x,y) heaviside(y-sin(x));
% using integral2
I1 = integral2(fun,0,pi/2,0,pi/2)

nx = 100; ny = 100;
x = linspace(0,pi/2,nx);
y = linspace(0,pi/2,ny);
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
Z = fun(X,Y);
% using trapz
I2 = trapz(y,trapz(x,Z.*(Z>0),2))
```

> ```
> I1 =
>
>     1.4674
>
>
> I2 =
>
>     1.4695
> ```

Comment: But that's numerical computation, not symbolic. It looks like the OP wants symbolic computation

Comment: He mentioned he wants the numerical answer, numerically calculating it is much better (computational performance) than using symbolic toolbox

Comment: OP is trying to compute the numerical answer _symbolically_, jugding by the question text and original tags. Of course numerically it's faster

Comment: yes it is numerical answer, but i meant it as double(integ).

Comment: actually it is answered in this following link: https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/579165-i-am-not-able-to-integrate-heaviside-y-f-for-x-0-to-pi-2-and-y-0-to-pi-2-only-syms-integration